# after submit button unable to show modal for 10seconds before navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In my app, I want, when a form submit, a modal or popup to show up for 10 - 15 seconds and then navigate to another page.

```
<td colspan=3><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="submit" type="submit">ADD TOPIC</button></td>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Edit Member Detail</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Success</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            var txttopicname = $('#txttopicname').val();
            var boardid = $('#boardid').val();
            var bclassid = $('#bclassid').val();
            var subjectid = $('#subjectid').val();

            if(txttopicname == '' )  
            {  
              $('#error_message').html("All Fields are required");  
            }
            else{
                $('#error_message').html('');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "topicadddb.php", 
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {txttopicname:txttopicname, boardid:boardid, bclassid:bclassid, subjectid:subjectid},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#myModal').modal('show').html(data);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        },10000);
                        window.location="topiclistdb.php"; //navigate
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

topicadddb.php:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['txttopicname'])) {
    $topicname  = $_POST['txttopicname'];

    $boardid = $_POST['boardid'];

    $bclassid = $_POST['bclassid'];

    $subjectid = $_POST['subjectid'];

    $s="INSERT INTO topicinfo (topicname,boardid,bclassid,subjectid,status) VALUES ( UPPER('$topicname'),'$boardid','$bclassid','$subjectid',0)";

//echo $s;

    mysqli_query($conn,$s) or die( mysqli_error());
    header('Location:topiclistdb.php');
}
?>
```

When I click submit button, it just fade for 1 second then directly goes to  the next page.

Comment: So move `window.location="topiclistdb.php";` to inside the timeout after the line `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` - you do not even need to hide the modal

Comment: Voting to close as `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. `

Comment: You hide the modal after 10 seconds but redirect immediately. You should move the ````window.location="topiclistdb.php";```` in the setTimeout section.

Comment: By the way, this is rather dangerous use of MySQL inserts without parameter validation. You should better use stored procedures instead of concatenating the insert string

Comment: i move window.location="topiclistdb.php"; to setTimeout section but i does not work. Neither modal show nor navigate to next page. Just fade page for 1second